# Sakai Connector browser issue while adding tools from liferay

Tags: iframe, liferay-6, sakai

I am using sakai-connector-portlet 1.1(for sakai 2.7.1) and Liferay 6.0.6. I am trying to add tools for a Sakai site. I am able to add tools in firefox browser. But when i am trying to add using Chrome, it is navigating from Liferay to sakai.

After clicking on Edit Tools, I am selecting the new Tools and after that clicking on continue button, i have three buttons Finish,Back Cancel. When i clicks Finish, it is navigating from liferay to Sakai. However Back,Cancel works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the Sakai Connector portlet. What are the allowed tools you have configured?

The portlet is designed to expose individual tools from Sakai and show them inside the portal (originally written for uPortal but also works in Liferay) - so things like Wiki, Forums, Resources, Profile all work really well since they are discrete tools.

You probably dont want to add the sakai.sitesetup tool to the list of allowed tools as that is a Sakai tool and allows you to add other tools to the Sakai site. And once you click Finish it performs a refresh which sounds like it is taking you to the main Sakai page inside the portlet.

Comment: But i want to add that tool, so that user can be able to select required tools. Thanks for reply.

Comment: It won't work though. The change you'll be making is on Sakai, not Liferay. And if they add a tool to a site in Sakai that isn't in the allowed list of tools, then it still won't show up in the portlet. Your best bet is to setup sites with a default set of tools so they are always available. You can do this with a toolOrder.xml config file in sakai.home. See here: http://www.unicon.net/node/1000